# zsh with different $PATH in login and non-login shell. Behavior not as it is defined

Tags: shell, path, homebrew, zsh

**edit** This question was asked on a wrong premise. See at the end **edit**

I am working on a Mac with zsh and my `$PATH` is read not as it should, so that I have two versions of path. One with homebrew at the end and one with homebrew at the beginning.

My assumption is that the non-login shell is reading `.zprofile` although it shouldn't. I got the information about the ZSH startup scripts here [Link](http://meta.ath0.com/2007/10/23/cleaning-up-bash-customizations/).

**Question:** How do I get the same `$PATH` for homebrew in both shells?

**Detailed:**

I am using the MacOS terminal and the one integrated into PyCharm (IDE Software).

1. I have installed homebrew which puts `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` into the `~/.zprofile`.
2. MacOS shell uses this this `$PATH`: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin`
   PyCharm shell uses this as `$PATH`: `/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` 
   As you can see `homebrew` is at the beginning in one and at the and in the other.
3. MacOS Testing which shell is used with `ps -o comm= $$`
   Terminal uses `-zsh` (I assume this as the login shell)
   PyCharm uses `/bin/zsh`(I assume this is the non-login shell)
4. If I understand the startup scripts correctly then the non-login shell in PyCharm does not read `.zprofile` so it shouldn't be able to see the homebrew path  and the MaxOS with the log-in shell should see the homebrew path at the beginning, because it reads `~/.zprofile` first.

**edit**
It seems like the problem lies within tmux.

in `~/.zprofile` is this line: `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`

after starting tmux, the zsh shows this `$path`: `/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/sbin`

when tmux is not running zsh shows this `$path`: `/opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin`

the order is switched.

**solution**
I used `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"` instead of `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` in the `~/.zprofile` and now the order in `$path` is the same in tmux.

Comment: `~/.zsprofile` is indeed processed by a login shell. If you are running a non-login zsh, it could be that one of the parent processes is a zsh login shell (did you check this?), or that one of the files processes by a non-login zsh sources .zprofile explicitly.

Comment: Unfortunately I was only able to find out that the parent process is PyCharm. But your theory sounds plausible.
I tested and found out, that it still behaves strange: PyCharm shows "$path:homebre/bin" and MacOS shows "homebrew/bin:$path"

Comment: I didn't say "the parent process", I said "the parent processes", plural; i.e. the parent of your PyCharm, and the parent of that, and so on, until you arrive at your login process. One of those processes could be a zsh login shell.

Comment: I know, but there is nothing I can see. "zsh < PyCharm < launchd < kernel_task"

Comment: I just realized by accident that PyCharm is behaving correct. 
I am using tmux every time I open the OS Terminal. Without tmux, the terminal shows everything right.

Comment: How did you verify that your zsh is not a login shell? Did you check `$-`?

Comment: I used `ps -o comm= $$` and the result was `-zsh` so I assumed it. 
I edited the post with a solution. I do not understand it, bit seems like it helped.

Comment: This looks like a login shell. Still I would do a `echo $-`, which is AFIK the only **reliable** way to find out.

Comment: I tried `echo $-`: 
PyCharm: is a login shell.
MacOS: is a login shell. tmux: is a login shell

Comment: So this should have resolved your question, because it is now clear, why your .zprofile has been processed.